# Dynamic function inside loop: i var is not visible

Tags: javascript

Take a look at the following code

```
//btns is an array passed as a parameter to a function
for(var i = 0, b; b = btns[i]; i++) {
    b.handler = function () {
        var a = btns[i].some_field; //undefined
        //the same for "b.some_field;"
    };
}
```

Why `btns[i]` is undefined?

**PS.** the code adds click handler on extjs buttons if that matters.

Comment: <del>Because you are missing `var btns = [];` somewhere before that code.</del>

Comment: @Nabil: That would result in a reference error instead. The problem is not with `btns` but with how closures work in JS.

Comment: Even though there might be simpler solutions to the problem, you should have a look at [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196) to understand *what* the problem is.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#54

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because by the time the inner function is called (which is after the loop is done) the value of `i` would be `btns.length` and therefore the value of `btns[i]` would be `undefined`.

You need to close over the value of `i` like this:

```
b.handler = function(i) {
    return function() {
        var a = btns[i].some_field;
    }
}(i);
```

It's important to note that although the variables have the same name, they're different variables; i.e. the inner variable shadows the outer, thereby "fixing" the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0, b; b = btns[i]; i++) {
  b.handler = function () {
    var a = this.btns[i].some_field; 
    //the same for "b.some_field;"
  };
}
```

give "this." in side the function we have to use "this" to point

Comment: Do you mean `this.some_field`? Because `b` *is* `btns[i]`. I don't think that each element in the array has a reference back to the array. Anyways, whether this works depends on *how* `b.handler` is called, which we don't know about.